# error, module neat has no attribute config

Tags: python, neat

The problem is in the `config = neat.config.Config()`. I have neat installed and I'm using Sublime on Windows. I have looked through some other similar questions and most say to install neat-python, but I have that, and others were to do with pycharm.

```
def run(config_path):
    config = neat.config.Config(neat.DefaultGenome, neat.DefaultReproduction, neat.DefaultSpeciesSet, neat.DefaultStagnation, config_path)
    p = neat.Population(config)
    winner = p.run(main,50)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    local_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    config_path = os.path.join(local_dir, "config-feedforward.txt")
    run(config_path)
```

Comment: What do you get from `dir(neat)`?

Comment: its too long to send but it isnt a directory

Answer (score 0):

you have a config to much

```
import os
import neat
def run(config_path):
    neat.util.
    config = neat.Config(neat.DefaultGenome, neat.DefaultReproduction, neat.DefaultSpeciesSet, neat.DefaultStagnation, config_path)
    p = neat.Population(config)
    winner = p.run(main,50)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    local_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    config_path = os.path.join(local_dir, "config-feedforward.txt")
    run(config_path)
```

Comment: that isn't ienough information you must have another problem, that doesn't condrn the configuration